# Getting error while using jsPdf Autotable

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Am trying to print the Data into the PDF so i used jsPdf , at that time the data's are not aligned properly into my PDF table . So i searched in many site's they referred me to use jsPdf Auto-table . Here the problem arises , before the injection of jsPdf Auto-table  every thing is working fine(without alignment) but after i insert

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.16/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

this into my **index.html** am getting error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined    (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the jspdf library **before** the jspdf-autotable plugin. See the [docs](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) for further information. You might also want to the latest version.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<!-- EDIT: For now, add this line between the libraries -->
<!-- The reason being that jspdf includes a version of requirejs which -->
<!-- jspdf-autotable currently is not expecting. You can also use version < 2.0.21 -->
<script>if (window.define) delete window.define.amd;</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<script>
var columns = ["ID", "Name", "Country"];
var rows = [
   [1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"],
   [2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"],
   [3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"]
];
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
doc.save('table.pdf');
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried that also buddy at that time am getting-------> doc.autoTable is not a function <-------  this error

Comment: I updated the answer with a work around for an issue with the latest version of jspdf and the latest versions of jspdf-autotable.

Comment: Need one clarification , var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');  in that line what does it mean by 'p' and 'pt ' ??? use ?

Comment: P means portrait and you can change to l for landscape if you wish. Pt means points and jspdf-autotable only supports that for now

Comment: Need your help bro . Pls go this Link ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561121/getting-trouble-while-trying-dynamic-data-in-jspdf-autotable         Waiting for your answer .

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related but for people who are trying to use this on Angular 4 project created by angular cli and got the doc.autoTable is not a function.
include jspdf and jspdf.plugin.autotable in .angular-cli.json file in scripts array

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
     "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.src.js"
  ],
```

then in the component you want to use auto table first import jspdf and jspdf-autotable

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import * as jpt from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

Then use as below. **You have to declare jpt variable before making the doc.autotable call**

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');    jpt; 
doc.autoTable(this.columns, this.data);
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 40, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

// Save the PDF
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: jspdf is a javascript file. The way you include javascript files in angular 2+ is using the script files. and you can use these scripts by importing them as ES module in a type script file.