# Getting trouble while trying Dynamic Data in jsPdf AutoTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Am trying to print the dynamic data into the PDF using jsPdf AutoTable .But am failed to do that. I searched in many site's but no one didn't said about dynamic data into the Row's. So here my question is , Is there any way to get the Dynamic data into the table row's if it so can some one clarify me pls .  Note : [ Here am not using HTML to store the Data into the Pdf, i got the data from the js directly ] .

```js
this.print=function(){
         {
          
          var mainData =this.printData(); // Here am getting Full Json data Here
          var steps = mainData.steps;   // From that data am Separating what i need
          var criticality = mainData.criticality;
          var categories = mainData.categories;
          var checkup = mainData.checkup;
          
            // This is For to Take the Steps Data alone
               $scope.getSteps = function(steps) {
                   var data = [];
                   for (var i = steps.length; i-- > 0;) {
                     data.push(steps[i].name+"\n"+"\n");
                   }
                   return data;
                 }
               
                     // Like wise am getting every single object data's 
                  $scope.getNumbersOfSubSteps = function(steps) {
                   var data = 0;
                   for (var i = 0 ; i < steps.length; i++) {
                     for (var j = 0; j<steps[i].steps.length; j++) {
                      }
                     data = j ;
                   }
                   return data;
                 }

                 // this is for Sub Proceeses
                 $scope.getSubProcesses = function(steps) {
                   var data = [];
                   for (var i = 0 ; i < steps.length; i++) {
                      for (var j = 0; j<steps[i].steps.length; j++) {
                          data.push(steps[i].steps[j].name+"\n");                  
                     }
                   }
                   return data;
                 }
                 
                  $scope.getCategories = function(categories) {
                   var data = [];
                   for (var i = categories.length; i-- > 0;) {
                     data.push(categories[i].name+"\n");
                   }
                   return data;
                 } 
                  
                  $scope.getCriticality = function(criticality) {
                   var data = [];
                   for (var i = criticality.length; i-- > 0;) {
                     data.push(criticality[i].name+"\n");
                   }
                   return data;
                 }
         
                 // Pdf Print Function Begins 
                  
                var columns = ["ProcessDescription", "Steps", "#ofSubProcesses", "SubSteps","Category","Criticality","CheckUp"];
                var processDescription =mainData.description;
                var processes= $scope.getSteps(steps);
                var NoOfSubProcess = $scope.getNumbersOfSubSteps(steps);
                var subProcesses = $scope.getSubProcesses(steps);
                console.log('Subprocsses length',subProcesses);
                var categories = $scope.getCategories(categories);
                var criticality = $scope.getCriticality(criticality);
                
                // The Problem Begins here , Am struggling to Get the Separate data's here !
                var rows = [
                                    [processDescription,processes,NoOfSubProcess,subProcesses,categories,criticality]
                            
                             ];
                
                var pdfsize='a1';
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',pdfsize);
     
                doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
                 theme: 'striped', // 'striped', 'grid' or 'plain'
                 styles: {
                       overflow: 'linebreak',
                       columnWidth: 'wrap'
                     },
                     beforePageContent: function(data) {
                         doc.text("Process Name :"+mainData.name, 40, 30);
                     },
                    columnStyles: {
                      1: {columnWidth: 'auto'}
                    }
                  });

                  doc.save(mainData.name+ pdfsize +".pdf");
            }
           
        
          
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic data? You can construct the row objects with  a loop before calling autotable for example?

Comment: Dynamic data mean's , var processes = $scope.getSteps(steps);  --> This process have three process into it , so if i use Process into that row it prints three data in same cell ,

Comment: You would have to transform processes to a format that matches the used by autotable.. If you look in the repo there is an examples/examples.js file in the repo which is using dynamic data if you want pointers.

Comment: i tried for loop to hit the data in the Row, But it doesn't reflect .

Comment: There you used getData() from someWhere right ? Let me check that and update you , Thanks bro :)

Comment: Sure! Its probably some issue with either the angular code or the transform code. If you post that for loop in the question i can take a look at it.

Comment: @Simon bengtsson Edit : I just put my Full code here, have a  Look at that ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118198/discussion-between-becky-and-simon-bengtsson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to replace this:

```
var rows = [
    [processDescription,processes,NoOfSubProcess,subProcesses,categories,criticality]
];
```

with something like this:

```
var rows = [];
for (var k = 0 ; k < processes.length; k++) {
    rows.push([
        processDescription,
        processes[k],
        NoOfSubProcess,
        subProcesses[k],
        categories[k],
        criticality[k]
    ]);
};
```

The rows parameter should be an array of arrays. What you are putting in there is basically an array of an array of arrays if I understood correctly.

Comment: Got a new weird problem !!! If possible Can you please gothrough  my problm   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647201/cannot-find-name-jspdf-in-typescript